In Spring ORM, ERROR - Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate]: No default constructor found
I have included the hibernate dependencies in pom.xml and the HibernateTemplate class that has been included also have the default constructor then why am I getting this error:

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate]: No default constructor found

Beans declared in Config.xml:
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" name="ds">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springorm"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" name="factory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref = "ds"></property>
        
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            </props>
        </property> 
        
        <property name="annotatedClasses"> 
            <list>
                <value>com.spring.orm.entities.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate" name="hibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"/>
    </bean>
    
    
    <bean class="com.spring.orm.dao.StudentDaoImpl" name="studentDao">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>


Dependencies included in pom.xml:
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>


Probably you need to create default (NoArgs) constructor in your bean , since sometimes it is required ti instantiate a certain bean

But I have already created that in all the beans.

configuration.xml

<!--local session factory bean configuration-->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
name="sessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.students.entities.Students</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.students.dao.StudentsDao" name="studentsDao" autowire="constructor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" 
name="transactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

studentdao.java
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public StudentsDao() {
}

public StudentsDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Transactional
public Integer insertData(Students students){
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(students);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    return 1;
}

pom.xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

your issue will resolve
If you're using Hibernate 5.x or later, you can still use Session directly with Spring's support. This approach allows you to have more control over your database interactions and transactions.
